# Define new list and recursively add items in the list by appending in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, append, new-operator, addition

I am trying to do some operation on the given list items and trying to declare a new list and add items to it that satisfy a certain condition. I have to call this function recursively. So, first time the list is null and i want to insert an item in it. Second time , it will have one element and adding another element makes two elements. Third time two elements are there, and add one more element and so on.

Please help me how to declare list in prolog and addr elements to it by appending in recursive function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to declare terms in Prolog; they exist once you write them down. So if you write [], it is the empty list. The things you mention are relations between two lists: One list, call it List0, and another list, call it List, which is List0 with additional elements. So you have a relation like

```
list0_list(List0, List) :-
    ....
```

which holds if List is List0 with the elements you want. You only have to describe when this relation holds, and you do this by stating the necessary conditions in the rule's body.